# How to pass parameters to the command object from Xaml for the button tool?

Tags: wpf

How to pass parameters to the command object from Xaml for the button tool?

```
<igRibbon:ButtonTool Id="btnFindEntity" Caption="Search" LargeImage="Images/Search.png" igRibbon:RibbonGroup.MaximumSize="ImageAndTextLarge" Command="{Binding RibbonSearchCommand}"/>
```

Please help me with the above code.. I have to pass a combo box and a text box value as parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values of the textbox and combobox form part of a business object which is your datacontext,you can pass it as **CommandParameter="{Binding}"**.If otherwise,Command being of type object,you can create a container for these two values and pass it on as well!